# How can I calculate the subgradient of this function?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, regularization, loss-functions

I am new to the concept of subgradient and am struggling hard while trying to calculate the sub-gradient of Absolute Loss Function with absolute regularization

$f(\theta) =  \sum_{k = 1}^M | y_k - \theta^T x_k | + \lambda \sum_{k=1}^M |\theta_k|$

First of all, I don't know where exactly this function is not differentiable at?

Secondly, how can I calculate its sub-gradient? Help will be much appreciated